# How do I print lists side by side in Python?

Tags: python

New user practicing lists and loops. My goal is create two list from my own input (range is 2 for quick testing, but want to get to 10). I have hit a wall on two problems:

1. I would like my lists to sit side by side ie.

First Name \t\t\t $77

Next Name \t\t\t $16

2. I don't know how to change my types so that int or float is not iterable error does not persists. I believe it'll help with my coded out max/min statements

My code:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
count = 0

for i in range(2):
    customers = input("Customers name? ")
    list1.append(customers)
    spent = float(input("Amount spent? "))
    list2.append(spent)
    count += spent
    averageSpent = count / 2 # change this when changing range

print("Name\t\t\tAmount")
# won't print side by side. how to use zip()?
print((*list1 + list2), sep = "\n") 
print("Total spending:\t\t $", count)
print("Average spending:\t $", averageSpent)

# keep getting 'object is not iterable'
#print("Most money spent:\t $", max(spent))
#print("Least money spent:\t $", min(spent))
```

My output is currently:

Customers name? work

Amount spent? 45

Customers name? please

Amount spent? 65

Name        Amount

work

please

45.0

65.0

Total spending:      $ 110.0

Average spending:    $ 55.0

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. In any case, I believe both these questions are duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523563/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable respectively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print 2 lists side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side)

Comment: These did, that you. I came across these before submitting my question but did not understand before. Taking the mental break and returning to these threads helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first issue that you have, the best way for you to print the output side by side would be to iterate over the list and print each value in the list. In addition to that, you can use f-strings which is a feature that we added with python 3.6 and it allows you to do stuff like this:

```
x = 10
print(f'{x+20}')
>> 30
```

you can read more about f-strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

Regarding the second issue that you're facing. You got this error because you were calling the max() function on a single float. the max function should be called for a list.

I've made some adjustments. Here is what the final code looks like:

```
list1 , list2 = [] , []
max_range = 2
count = 0

for i in range(max_range):
    customer_name = input("Customer name: ")
    list1.append(customer_name)

    spent = float(input("Amount Spent: "))
    list2.append(spent)

    count += spent
    averageSpent = count / max_range

print("Name\t\t\tAmount")
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(f'{list1[i]} \t\t\t$ {list2[i]}')
print("Total spending:\t\t $", count)
print("Average spending:\t $", averageSpent)

print("Most money spent:\t $", max(list2))
print("Least money spent:\t $", min(list2))
```

**Edit:** using the zip function might be another option for printing the two outputs side by side using tuples. However, since you've already said that you're new to these topics I think that you should stay away from zip (for the time being) until you feel comfortable with lists.

Answer (score 1):

Printing things side by side is answered here: [Print 2 lists side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side)

The error about a float or int not being iterable is because you are calling `max(spent)` instead of `max(list2)`. The function `max()` expects a list or other iterable object.

Answer (score 0):

bikemule is correct about the iterables. You need to call `max` with a list, not a single number. (What would `max(101)` return? It doesn't quite make sense.)

To make the two lists appear side-by-side, you can use `zip` combined with a `for` loop. It will turn the lists into sets of tuples that then will appear in an almost-tabular format when printed.

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [4, 5, 6]
for col_a, col_b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print("A_Item: %s  |   B_Item: %d" %(col_a, col_b))
```

Returns:

```
A_Item: 1  |   B_Item: 4
A_Item: 2  |   B_Item: 5
A_Item: 3  |   B_Item: 6
```