# Print Players With Their Score

Tags: python, list, ipl

How can I  print player’s names with their scores?

** (Player) Has (Score) Points

Here's My Code

```
#python 3.7.1
print ("Hello, Dcoder!")

players = ["Akshit","Bhavya", "Hem", "Jayu", "Jay M", "Jay Savla", "Miraj", "Priyank", "PD", "Pratik"]
score = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#0 = Akshit
#1 = Bhavya
#2 = Hem
#3 = Jayu
#4 = Jay M
#5 = Jay Savla
#6 = Miraj
#7 = Priyank
#8 = PD
#9 = Pratik
#10 = Shamu

print (players)
print (score)

players.append("Shamu")
score. append(0)

#RRvCSK
score[9] = (score[9]+100)
score[7] = (score[7]+50)
score[4] = (score[4]+30)

print ("Result")

print (players)
print (score)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print 2 lists side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
players = ["Akshit","Bhavya", "Hem", "Jayu", "Jay M", "Jay Savla", "Miraj", "Priyank", "PD", "Pratik"]
score = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
   
for player, sc in zip(players, score):
    print("{} has {} points".format(player, sc))
```

Output:

```
Akshit has 0 points
Bhavya has 1 points
Hem has 2 points
Jayu has 3 points
Jay M has 4 points
Jay Savla has 5 points
Miraj has 6 points
Priyank has 7 points
PD has 8 points
Pratik has 9 points
```

`zip`[1](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) makes an iterator by aggregating elements from each of the iterables (here, we have `players` and `score` lists). Every element from `players` and `score` are taken together and then printed to the console on the next line.

Comment: Since OP is still new to coding, i suggest you explain what you did

Answer (score 0):

Use dict:

```
players = ["Akshit","Bhavya", "Hem", "Jayu", "Jay M", "Jay Savla", "Miraj", "Priyank", "PD", "Pratik"]
score = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

dct = {k: v for k, v in zip(players, score)}

dct["Akshit"] += 100
print(dct)
```

### Output

```
{'Akshit': 100,
 'Bhavya': 0,
 'Hem': 0,
 'Jay M': 0,
 'Jay Savla': 0,
 'Jayu': 0,
 'Miraj': 0,
 'PD': 0,
 'Pratik': 0,
 'Priyank': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy, if I understood the question. I am pretty sure it is this:

```
#python 3.7.1
print ("Hello, Dcoder!")

players = ["Akshit","Bhavya", "Hem", "Jayu", "Jay M", "Jay Savla", "Miraj", "Priyank", "PD", "Pratik"]
score = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#0 = Akshit
#1 = Bhavya
#2 = Hem
#3 = Jayu
#4 = Jay M
#5 = Jay Savla
#6 = Miraj
#7 = Priyank
#8 = PD
#9 = Pratik
#10 = Shamu

print(players)
print(score)

players.append("Shamu")
score.append(0)

#RRvCSK
score[9] = (score[9]+100)
score[7] = (score[7]+50)
score[4] = (score[4]+30)

print("Result is: ")

for i in range(11):
    print(f"{players[i]} has {str(score[i])} points")
```

All I did was add a for loop which prints the player's name and score each time.