# Printing a for loop inside a for loop correctly in Python

Tags: python, nested-for-loop

Hope someone can help me out here.
I am using a for loop inside a for loop in Python. That is a nested-for-loop and I want to map the results together once.
At the moment the results are displayed correctly once and then incorrectly repeated. This is my code snippet.

```
for country in ["USA", "Nigeria", "Germany", "India", "Britain"]:
    for code in ["+1", "+234", "+49", "+91", "+44"]:
        print(country, code)
        
print("Done")
```

The result I am trying to achieve is this one.

```
USA +1
Nigeria +234
Germany +49
India +91
Britain +44
Done!
```

But what I am getting at the moment is this one.

```
USA +1
USA +234
USA +49
USA +91
USA +44
Nigeria +1
Nigeria +234
Nigeria +49
Nigeria +91
Nigeria +44
Germany +1
Germany +234
Germany +49
Germany +91
Germany +44
India +1
India +234
India +49
India +91
India +44
Britain +1
Britain +234
Britain +49
Britain +91
Britain +44
Done
```

Is there a way I can improve it and get the desired result?
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you show a small snippet of the output that you desire?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side?

Answer (score 4):

You could zip the countries and codes to match the corresponding elements:

```
countries = ["USA", "Nigeria", "Germany", "India", "Britain"]
codes = ["+1", "+234", "+49", "+91", "+44"]

for country, code in zip(countries, codes):
    print(country, code)
```

(or for nicer formatting: `print(f"{country} {code}")`).

When do loop inside the loop you print *each* code for *each* country, which is what you see in your current output.

Zip does exactly what it sounds like, i.e. it acts as a zipper:

```
list(zip(countries, codes))
```

gives

```
[("USA", "+1"), ("Nigeria", "+234"), ...]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
countries = ["USA", "Nigeria", "Germany", "India", "Britain"];
codes = ["+1", "+234", "+49", "+91", "+44"];

for i in range(len(countries)):
    print(countries[i], codes[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's what you're waiting for but here is a code that send the result you're waiting for :

```
country = ["USA", "Nigeria", "Germany", "India", "Britain"]
code = ["+1", "+234", "+49", "+91", "+44"]
for i in range(4):
    print(country[i], code[i])
print('done')
```

Comment: Note that range(4) is [0, 1, 2, 3], i.e. one short

Comment: Very much appreciated. It helps.