# How to display two lists at the same time

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
x = ['34', '22', '45']
y = ['red', 'blue', 'grean']
```

I need to output these two lists together

```
34, red
22, blue
45, grean
```

i tried to get it all through for in

```
for a, b in x, y:
    print(a, b)
```

but i get an error

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: You can use `zip`, `for a, b in zip(x,y)`

Comment: print(a+", "+b)

Comment: `print` function takes a single value to print, so you need to combine them somehow. If you want exactly the output above then you need string formatting. For something quick you could pass them as a tuple: `print((a, b))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print 2 lists side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053979/print-2-lists-side-by-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = ['34', '22', '45']
y = ['red', 'blue', 'grean']

for a, b in zip(x, y):
    print(f"{a}, {b}")
```

Output:

```
34, red
22, blue
45, grean
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

```py
x = ['34', '22', '45']
y = ['red', 'blue', 'green'] // you made a typo in 'green' so i fixed it
for i, x in enumerate(x):
    print(f"{x}, {y[i]}")
```

##### It returns this:

```
34, red
22, blue
45, green
```